# The Gunn diode and the two valley theory

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In today lecture of microwave and radar my teacher explained about the Gunn diode.
He said it is made up of only one type of matrial e.g. $GaAS$ as shown in (a) part of the image.
[image: image 1]
<sub>(source: [britneyspears.ac](http://britneyspears.ac/physics/highfields/images/Image93.gif))</sub>

He said that there is no depletion layer and no gate so this diode conducts in reverse bias. He explained its working by using two valley theory. I have mainly two questions which emerged from this lecture:

> 1. Why a Gunn diode is called a diode as it conducts in both the directions.

My teacher said that there are two valleys in the conduction band as shown. And the electron in the lower valley has lower effective mass as compared to that of in upper valley.

[image: image 2]
<sub>(source: [britneyspears.ac](http://britneyspears.ac/physics/highfields/images/Image79.gif))</sub>

So my question is :

> 2. Since electron in the lower valley is more near to the nucleus so its velocity should be more so its effective mass should be more because $m^*=\dfrac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$in the lower valley

Comment: Engineers are lazy, and when they see a piece of semiconductor with two wires (terminals) they call it a "diode". A "Gunn diode" is not a diode at all in the conventional sense of the word but unfortunately the name stuck. Over the years many people tried to call it something else, such as Gunn device and some such but failed. As regards to your other question it is a misunderstanding to think of the bottom of the valley as being closer in 3-space to anything, especially to the nucleus. Your curves are in "k-space", that is energy v. wavenumber, not energy v. position.

Comment: @hyportnex Perhaps that comment should be converted to an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think a Gunn Diode is called "diode" because it was named also "Vacuum Diode", a vacuum diode has an anode and cathode and it conducts in one way. As the article about [gunn diode](http://911electronic.com/gunn-diode/) says.
2. You have right about that.

Comment: This answer seems fine, but just so you know, having a username similar to web sites you link to triggers a few spam filters (it's a common pattern, unfortunately), so be aware.

Comment: I don't understand your answer to part 2. What happens in k-space stays in k-space, or Bloch waves representing extended electronic structure are not tied to nuclei.